# Function that opens file for editing

Tags: functions, load

Is there a function that can be called to open a file for editing? I know how to open and edit files in Vim, and I know I can use `:e filename`, but is there a built in function I can call that does this?

If a function exists that does this, there probably is a reason for it to exist in addition to the `:e` command and knowing about its existence and what it is called would enable me to look at it in the help and see the purpose of its existence.

One problem with using `:e filepath` is it gets confused when there are spaces in the path. I tried surrounding the path in quotes, and this allows the command to run without error. But then I can't save, as it seems to think the file is inside a non-existent directory. If I escaped the spaces with a `\` character, it works when the command is run directly, but it is causing problems inside a plugin test of mine. I haven't figured out a good way to ask for help with that exact problem yet, so I want to keep this question focused on how to consistently open a path for editing regardless of what characters may be in it. A built in function to do this would be nice, but now I see making my own would be good as well.

Comment: Not sure why you would need this. If you want to use it in a script you can just use `e filename` in the script. If you really need it for some reason you can write it a custom function that takes an argument called file and then calls `e a:file`.

Comment: I agree with @Tumbler41: it looks like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754). You should give more details about what you want to do in the first place.

Comment: It could be useful to see the "why" of this question. For example, the OP could have something like Emacs in mind, where each operation is either an interactive function (command) or a function, but in any case has a function associated. In Vim, things are not so "canonical", so to speak. It would be more elegant perhaps for Vim to be able to expose a more powerful API. In any case, the question doesn't show its purpose.

Comment: No, actually I asked the exact question I wanted an answer to. Sometimes I don't want help solving a specific problem, I just want an answer to a specific question. I tried looking for a built in function that does this and could not find one. If there is one, I would like to know about it. If there is not, I would accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: Also, please stop making it really hard to like this community. If this is not the correct place to ask a very specific and clear Vim question, then nothing is.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to help :) I was suggest that you edit your question (specifying a "why") so that the question could be taken out of "on hold".

Comment: Voted for reopening, after the edit - pun intended :) As to the issue, not being able to call something like "edit <filename>" from a plugin, when <filename> has spaces, I think `:h fnameescape()` can help, e.g. the example found right there: `:exe "edit" . fnameescape(fname)` may be what you are after.

Comment: I finished making a function for this. You can see it as the edit method of this File class: https://github.com/still-dreaming-1/vim-elhiv/blob/develop/src/File.vim

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but (after a quick look) perhaps you should surround the `.` with spaces to concatenate "e " and the `editable_path` (?)

Comment: @VanLaser Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean though? If you mean the `.` on line 27, that is the concatenation operator. Although you seem to understand that... I am confused.

Comment: @VanLaser Oh do you mean as a code style suggestion? To make the code clearer?

Comment: Scratch that, I was wrong :) I always use spaces, but they are not necessary. But if your error is there, try to enclose `editable_path` inside a `fnameescape()` call.

Comment: @VanLaser That is awesome! My code is working for me in the ways I have used it as is. But that is definitely better than just escaping spaces. The example in the help is the exact scenario I am using it in. That function is specifically for this exact problem.

Comment: Cool :) In this case, maybe you want to look at `:h function-list` to see what (more) functions are available - they may further simplify your code.

Comment: `:h function-list` is great! I have been using `:h functions`, (which tells me about function-list...), but I like the way function-list is organize by category. Actually part of the reason I was writing a library was to make an easier to lookup wrapper around some of the built in functions. Well that is still something I need, but it is good know the different options for looking stuff up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that does this. It is not tested, but it is based on File.edit() from https://github.com/still-dreaming-1/vim-elhiv/blob/develop/src/File.vim, which I did test.

```
function! Edit(filepath)
    execute "e ".fnameescape(a:filepath)
endfunction
```

Comment: I sometimes typo `:E` instead of `:e`: `command! -nargs=1 -complete=file E call Edit(<q-args>)` helps.